# Premature Session Timeout

Tags: .net, iis

We have an application built using MVC, jQuery and having an issue with Premature session timeout.

The session is timing out exactly after 10 minutes whereas the setting on IIS is 60 minutes

Is there any other setting that may be forcing session to time out in 10 minutes?

checked and found that App Pool is not recycling. 
All the other settings pertaining to app pool (i.e. recycle, idle time ) are checked and verified.

Any suggestion, help would be of great help....Thanks

Regards
AB

Comment: Could you show your web.config?